# How to save module param to the database in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to update my module param in the database. I try to use the following code:

```
if (!$params->get('is_installed')) 
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $params->set('is_installed', 1);

    $sql = 'UPDATE '.$db->QuoteName('#__modules').' SET params = \''.(string) $params.'\' WHERE title = \'My module\'';
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $db->query();

    // $params->get('is_installed') returns 1 - OK
}
```

but it doesn't want to change the param value in the database (All the time I have value "0"). The $params string is correct within the query, because if I do it manually the SQL query works. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Module parameters are stored automatically with Joomla. All you have to do it define the parameter in the XML file. To call it,  use the following:

```
$params->get('is_installed');
```

**Update:**

```
if($params->get('is_installed') == 0){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    //rest of database query
}
```

Comment: I have the xml configuration file, but I want to change the param value.

Comment: what is the purpose of the parameter?

Comment: don't attempt to update the json directly with sql use the module api and save properly. You are going to need a JRegistry object.

Comment: I do some SQL query if the value is equal to 0.